# How to load the store in vue when the app first loads

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to load products from my pinia store when my Vue app first loads.

This is my app.js

```
import {createApp} from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./Router/index";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(createPinia())
    .mount("#app")
```

And this is my store:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";

const state = {
    cart: [],
    order: {},
    customer: {},
    loading: true,
    error: null,
    products: [],
};

export const useCartStore = defineStore("shopState", {
    state: () => state,
    actions: {
        async getProducts() {
            try {
                this.loading = true;
                const response = await axios.get("/api/product");
                this.products = response.data.data;
                this.loading = false;
            } catch (error) {
                this.error = error;
            }
        },
        addToCart({ item }) {
            const foundProductInCartIndex = this.cart.findIndex(
                (cartItem) => item.slug === cartItem.slug
            );

            if (foundProductInCartIndex > -1) {
                this.cart[foundProductInCartIndex].quantity += 1;
            } else {
                item.quantity = 1;
                this.cart.push(item);
            }
        },
        removeProductFromCart({ item }) {
            this.cart.splice(this.cart.indexOf(item), 1);
        },
        clearCart() {
            this.cart.length = 0;
        },
        clearCustomer() {
            this.customer = {};
        },
        clearOrder() {
            this.order = {};
        },
        updateCustomer(customer) {
            this.customer = customer;
        },
        updateOrder(order) {
            this.order = order;
        },
        getSingleProduct(slug) {
            return this.products.find((product) => product.slug === slug);
        },
    },
    getters: {
        getCartQuantity() {
            return this.cart.reduce(
                (total, product) => total + product.quantity,
                0
            );
        },
        getOrderDetails() {
            return this.order;
        },
        getCartContents() {
            return this.cart;
        },
        getCustomer() {
            return this.customer;
        },
        getCartTotal() {
            return this.cart.reduce(
                (total, product) => total + product.price * product.quantity,
                0
            );
        },
    },
    persist: true,
});
```

I would like to call `getProducts` when the app loads. I am able to do this using Vue2 but not sure how to do this with the new composition API version of Vue. Please can someone advise how I can do this?

Comment: How did you do so with Vue 2?  The process would probably be the same.  Most likely that process was importing the store in your app's root component and calling the `getProducts` action in the created lifecycle hook.  If using `<script setup>` there is no created hook you need to specify so just putting the call inside script setup is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load the products once the app is loaded, you can use the `onMounted()` hook in the composition API.

https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted

On the component where you want to load the products:

```
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useCartStore } from '../stores/storeName.js';
const store = useCartStore()
onMounted(() => {

store.getProducts()
})
</script>
```

**Note: I'm using `<script setup>` here. But if you're using the `setup()` hook you need to manually return the function**

https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html